# Combobox anidado - Problema al editar

Tags: javascript

Buenas espero me ayuden en lo siguiente. Tengo 4 select(combobox) de los cuales 2 están anidados las cuales son cat_id y area_id. Al momento de editar,el combobox anidado se guarda con valores nulos, ocasionando que se elimine(oculte) de mi datatable.¿Como puedo solucionar este problema?

```js
function editar(part_id){
   $.post("../../controller/crud.php?op=mostrar",{part_id : part_id}, function(data, status){
     
    data = JSON.parse(data);
    console.log(data);
       
        $('#fecha_crea').val(data.fecha_crea);
        $('#num_fol').val(data.num_fol);
        $('#doc_id').val(data.doc_id);
        $('#part_descr').val(data.part_descr);
        $('#person').val(data.person);
        $('#telefono').val(data.telefono);
        $('#cat_id').val(data.cat_id);
        $('#area_id').val(data.area_id);
        $('#pro_id').val(data.pro_id);
        $('#part_id').val(data.part_id);
   });
    $("#modalcrud").modal('show');
}
```

Comment: por que no usas promesas???

Comment: en teoria lo que pasa es que se esta ejecutando tu lógica antes de que reciba la informacion del servidor... si haces un request con promesa, el sistema esperara a tener la informacion para mostrarla...

Comment: ha y no tiene que ver con php, ni con mysql...